# Two Step Authentication of Firebase do every time login once register in from this open source code of Quickblox

Tags: java, android, firebase-authentication, quickblox, q-municate

```js
package com.quickblox.q_municate.ui.activities.authorization;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.quickblox.auth.session.QBSessionManager;
import com.quickblox.q_municate.R;
import com.quickblox.q_municate.ui.activities.forgotpassword.ForgotPasswordActivity;
import com.quickblox.q_municate.utils.KeyboardUtils;
import com.quickblox.q_municate.utils.ValidationUtils;
import com.quickblox.q_municate_core.models.AppSession;
import com.quickblox.q_municate_core.models.LoginType;
import com.quickblox.q_municate_db.managers.DataManager;
import com.quickblox.q_municate_user_service.model.QMUser;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.OnCheckedChanged;
import butterknife.OnClick;

public class LoginActivity extends BaseAuthActivity {

    @Bind(R.id.remember_me_switch)
    SwitchCompat rememberMeSwitch;

    public static void start(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getContentResId() {
        return R.layout.activity_login;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initFields(savedInstanceState);
        setUpActionBarWithUpButton();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.login_email_button)
    void loginQB(View view) {
        if (checkNetworkAvailableWithError()) {
            login();
        }
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.facebook_connect_button)
    void loginFB(View view) {
        if (checkNetworkAvailableWithError()) {
            loginType = LoginType.FACEBOOK;
            startSocialLogin();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                startLandingScreen();
                break;
            default:
                super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startLandingScreen();
    }

    @OnCheckedChanged(R.id.remember_me_switch)
    void rememberMeCheckedChanged(boolean checked) {
        appSharedHelper.saveSavedRememberMe(checked);
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.forgot_password_textview)
    void forgotPassword(View view) {
        ForgotPasswordActivity.start(this);
    }

    private void initFields(Bundle bundle) {
        title = getString(R.string.auth_login_title);
        rememberMeSwitch.setChecked(true);
    }

    private void login() {
        KeyboardUtils.hideKeyboard(this);

        loginType = LoginType.EMAIL;

        String userEmail = emailEditText.getText().toString();
        String userPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString();

        if (new ValidationUtils(this).isLoginDataValid(emailTextInputLayout, passwordTextInputLayout,
                userEmail, userPassword)) {

            showProgress();
            boolean ownerUser =   QBSessionManager.getInstance().getSessionParameters() != null && userEmail.equals(QBSessionManager.getInstance().getSessionParameters().getUserEmail());
            if (!ownerUser) {
                DataManager.getInstance().clearAllTables();
            }

            login(userEmail, userPassword);
        }
    }
}
```

I modified Q-municate powered by QuickBlox (which is open source) GitHub code. But, in this app code (when i try to login from two step Authentication by firebase he login successfully. But whenever i open app again after sometime like half an hour, the Q-Municate app again comes on first splash page of app and start again procedure. It means when i login first time successfully by mobile number then why each time take from first step whenever i open the application of Q-Municate. How i can solve this issue.

Comment: Add codes to your question. That will help.

Comment: Which Activity code i should add in question 
like BaseAuthActivity.java, 
LandingActivity.java, 
LoginActivity.java, 
SignupActivity.java, 
SplashActivity.java

Comment: Add the login activity.

Comment: I am using only login by mobile number.

Comment: I took a look at the open sourced quickblox mainfest code and saw that the SplashActivity is the first starting activity. Anyways my point is this, you must check `remember_me_switch` in the LoginActivity to ensure that the `(QBSessionManager.getInstance().getSessionParameters() != null && appSharedHelper.isSavedRememberMe())` returns true.

Comment: i checked this code and the code which you told me it's already include in splash activity. Then, How to solve this issue.

Comment: I am aware, I meant is there not a checkbox with a `"remember_me_switch"` text in your LoginActivity?

Comment: Yes. There is a checkbox in the LoginActivity. Then How to solve this issue. Please help me to sort out this issue.